# Is there any way to call SelectedIndexChanged.BeginInvoke or similar method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a list of items that I want to set from a cookie on Page_Load(). It's a VERY long web form over top of SharePoint. I don't want to call each method for each control's event, but that's exactly what I'm doing right now. In other words, I don't need to know what the method is called for each control within the page, I just need to invoke it.

*Edit -- Also autopostback is set to true for each control, and I handle the event in page load with Page.IsPostback. I read somewhere that the selectindexchanged event will not fire from pageload, so that's why I've been investigating ugly work-arounds.

Current code:

```
enter code here
foreach (Control C in GPC.GetAllControls(this.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderMain").Controls))
                {
                    if (C == null) continue;
                    if (C is TextBox)
                    {
                        TextBox T = (TextBox)C;
                        if (cookie.Values[C.ID] != null)
                        {
                            T.Text = cookie.Values[C.ID];
                        }
                    }
                    else if (C is DropDownList)
                    {
                        DropDownList D = (DropDownList)C;
                        if (cookie.Values[C.ID] != null)
                        {
                            D.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(cookie.Values[C.ID]);

                            switch (C.ID)
                            {
                                case "DropDownListCategory":
                                    onChangeCategory(sender, e);
                                    break;
                                case "DropDownListContractType":
                                    DropDownListContractType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
                                    break;
                                case "DropDownListITPurchase":
                                    onChangeITPurchase(sender, e);
                                    break;
                                case "DropDownListServiceContract":
                                    onChangeServiceContract(sender, e);
                                    break;
                                case "DropDownListPOM":
                                    onChangePOMChoice(sender, e);
                                    break;
                //ETC.
                            }

                        }

                    }
```

Some past attempts that were abandoned this morning, each one within some comment delimiters:

```
/*
                            D.AutoPostBack = true;
                            D.SelectedIndex = 0;

                            System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() {
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                                D.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(cookie.Values[C.ID]);
                            });
                            T.Start();
                            */




                            /* this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                                   this.GetType(),
                                   "ValidateAndStore",
                                   "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>" +
                                   "$('[id$=" + D.ID + "]').prop('selectedIndex',"+int.Parse(cookie.Values[C.ID])+");" +

                                   "</script>"); */
                            /* this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                                   this.GetType(),
                                   "ValidateAndStore",
                                   "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>" +
                                   "$('[id$=" + D.ID + "]').selectedIndex=" + int.Parse(cookie.Values[C.ID]) + ";" +

                                   "__doPostBack(ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_" + D.ID + ",'onchange');" +
                                   "</script>");*/
```

Comment: Include code that you have tried.

Comment: Done and done sir.